# If I'm using a Promise.all to call a lambda.invoke, does the invocation type matter

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

If I use a `Promise.all` and `map()` to call a `lambda.invoke`, will the `InvocationType` of `Event` vs `RequestResponse` even matter?

Won't it still be running the invokes in parallel?

```
function get1(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            FunctionName: 'myLambda', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
            InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
            Payload: { id },
        };

        lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(new Error('error'));
            } else {
                const result = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    }).catch(e => Promise.resolve({ error: 'Error has occurred.' }));
}

exports.getDetails = list => Promise.all(list.map(get1))
    .then((response) => {
        return result;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('oops ', error);
    });
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by using Promise.all to call ... etc? Promise.all doesn't call anything

Comment: updated OP, kinda sleepy and got lazy

Comment: well, `list.map(get1)` will run in it's entirety (of course, not the asynchronous parts) before `Promise.all` is invoked with the array of promises returned by `get1` ... what `lambda.invoke` does is not relevant to `Promise.all` - if you were to run that code without using Promises, how would the lamda.invokes behave?

Comment: is this part right?      }).catch(e => Promise.resolve({ error: 'Error has occurred.' }));     I'm not sure this Promise relates to anything